# Line chart with two series based on single column values

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, mschart

I want to build a line chart based on this table:
[image: table]
where each different `KPIName` has its own line on the chart.
How should I do this?
I tried this:

```
foreach (KPI_PG kpi in _PG.KPI_PG)
{
    Series currentPG = new Series(kpi.KPIName);
    chrt_PGByYear.Series.Add(currentPG);
    currentPG.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
    currentPG.BorderWidth = 3;
    currentPG.XValueType = ChartValueType.String;
    currentPG.XValueMember = "Year";
    currentPG.YValueType = ChartValueType.Int32;
    currentPG.YValueMembers = "Value";
}
```

but it doesn't work because of the same chart name.

Comment: Your table shows 3 different  kpiNames in 5 rows. do you want 3 series or 5? how could the line look with 3 different 'years' as strings? you should recheck your data..

Answer (score 0):

Series names must be unique.  You should check if the series exists already and if it does then don't add it.  Otherwise add the series.

```
private void createNewSeries(String SeriesName)
{
    if(chrt_PGByYear.Series.IsUniqueName(SeriesName))
    {
        Series currentPG = chrt_PGByYear.Series.Add(SeriesName);
        currentPG.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
        currentPG.BorderWidth = 3;
        currentPG.XValueType = ChartValueType.String;
        currentPG.XValueMember = "Year";
        currentPG.YValueType = ChartValueType.Int32;
        currentPG.YValueMembers = "Value";
    }
}
```

Then you could use it like:

```
foreach (KPI_PG kpi in _PG.KPI_PG)
{
    createNewSeries(kpi.KPIName);
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work properly. This code shows only one line for last series added, based on all values in DataSource.

Comment: Can you show us your code where you set your datasource?

Comment: I've changed it already, but it was something like this:
`private void FillChart (DataTable table) {
    chrt_PGByYear.DataSource = table;
    foreach (KPI_PG kpi in _PG.KPI_PG)
            {
                createNewSeries(kpi.KPIName);
            }
}`

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be impossible. I just filled this chart manually, using `chrt_PGByYear.Series[serieName].Points.AddXY()` method.